# Referenced Entities in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sys.dm-sql

Trying to get the objects referenced within stored procedure dynamically. Below code doesn't work when it's dynamic

```
DECLARE @procname VARCHAR(50) = 'GetTempBondInformation'
SELECT  QUOTENAME('dbo.' + @procname ,'''')
SELECT  DISTINCT referenced_entity_name  FROM    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(QUOTENAME('dbo.' + @procname ,''''), 'OBJECT')
```

Whereas below code works fine.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT referenced_entity_name  FROM    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.GetTempBondInformation', 'OBJECT')
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

(remove the quoting)

```
DECLARE @procname VARCHAR(50) = 'GetTempBondInformation'
SELECT  DISTINCT 
     referenced_entity_name  
FROM    
     sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + @procname, 'OBJECT')
```